# Arduino OR operator

Tags: programming

I have been trying OR conditional operator in a if condition statement in my arduino program and the result is not what I expected.

My program:

```
// three variables assigned to const int datatype as the
// pin numbers they are assigned to are  going to remain 
// constant through out the program.
const int led1=10;
const int led2=11;
const int led3=12;

void setup(){
  // assigning the pins as input/output.
  pinMode(10,INPUT);
  pinMode(11,INPUT);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  control();
}

void control()
{
  int task1 = digitalRead(led1);
  int task2 = digitalRead(led2);
  if (task1==HIGH || task2==HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(led3,HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(led3,LOW);
  }
}
```

if the 'IF' conditional statement used without 'OR' operator is working fine that is not including both the tasks instead only one task either task1 or task2, else it is working without errors but the result is not as expected.
hardware part is all fine. i reckon that there is a problem with the OR || operator.

Comment: The 'or' operator is fine, your error lies elsewhere. But you do not give enough detail to help people diagnose your problem. How did you test the program? What behavior do you expect? What behavior does it show instead?

Comment: Could you try the `^` operator instead of (`||`), if this works for you, I'll explain it in greater detail.

Comment: I would also not advice using "led" as input. You might want to rename it to button or whatever other input device you're using.

Comment: @EdgarBonet - my objectice is to switch on the 3rd led pin high if any of the tasks i have assigned in my programme goes high. for example i have two push buttons thats assigned to task1 and task2 respectively.so when i press either of the push button the 3rd led pin must go high instead its low. i have tested it on PCB which has an atmega328 IC and the IDE is arduino IDE.

Comment: @FuaZe - i tried your input idea,but that didnt work as well. and i have no idea how i can use the bitwiseXOR operator for my application.

Comment: Could you please show the circuit schematic? How did you wire the LED on output 12? And the push-buttons? And why are those push-buttons called “led”?

Comment: Okay, could you specify when you want the led3 to go high. The code you have does it if any of these two is high and/or when both are high. What result do you think it should've had, or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @EdgarBonet@FuaZe. thank you foremost for helping me out through this problem. i am a beginner to arduino platform thats why the variable name led occured to a push button  :-D. i wil make sure i work on the ethics of programming. your work is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct for what you described you want it to do - raise `led3` when either or both of `led1` or `led2` is high, and make it low otherwise. Some things to check:

- Do the push-buttons pull their respective pins HIGH? (Pulling LOW is more common).
- Are the pins pulled to ground with a 5K or 10K resistor, and not left floating, when the respective button is not active?
- Real buttons need to be de-bounced. They behave as if their contacts bounce several times before making contact (even though that isn't really what happens). If this is an experiment and you hold the button down, even briefly, you should get proper results without de-bouncing, but it's something to be aware of as you move on.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't getting the expected result, as JRobert suggested you should look at your hardware. Ensure pull-ups/downs are being used correctly, your interpretation of your hardware's logic is correct (positive/negative logic), and maybe even use a simple sketch to check that everything is working correctly. Firstly I would simplify the control function. You could try replacing the OR with a bitwise OR, or changing your variables to booleans. Realistically, more code and a diagram illustrating your implementation would help us reproduce and troubleshoot this with you. I'm a little confused as to whether pins 10 & 11 are LEDs or Buttons. I would be happy to help you get a test program together if you can provide more detail. :)

```
void control()
{
    boolean task1 = digitalRead(led1);
    boolean task2 = digitalRead(led2);

    // Note that the if isn't needed
    digitalWrite(led3, (task1 || task2));

    // If your buttons use negative logic
    // digitalWrite(led3, (!task1 || !task2));
}
```

For humour-sake when I hit a problem that doesn't make sense, I rework my logic to break down the problem and output in stages, or use the Serial library to output what is going on periodically.

- [Arduino Serial Reference](http://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/serial)
- [Arduino Serial Tutorial](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson4.html)

Typically for inputs and outputs I define a structure which buffers everything per IO, and write my code with a loop-based mentality, much like how a game loop is implemented in video games. It is easy to print and trace when troubleshooting, and the positive/negative/default-state logic is abstracted. This will help you get started if you are curious.

- [Game Loop Example](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/the-game-loop)